# is it possible not to show app part titles?

Tags: web-part

I've made a site that shows one list with links twice, but with different views.
The titles above the two web parts now say "Links (1)" and "Links (2)". In the text above the web parts I already explain what the purpose of the lists is, so i do not need these titles, especially not since they have this funny (1) and (2). Is it possible not to show these titles?
Or does someone have another solution?

Answer (score 0):

When you edit the webpart you have to option to change or deactivate the titles.

[image]

Change it to "None" and the title will be gone.

Your titles have (1) and (2) because they are the same. Once they are different (1) and (2) will be gone.